# How can we use the android developer fundamentals V2 (concepts and codelabs) without an internet connection (offline)?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-developer-tools

Well, I need to learn how to program applications on Android,i start this course https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/overview-v2 and for economic reasons, I dont have an internet connection very often.
**Is there any possibility to obtaining the V2 course of concepts and codelabs in pdf?**
I know it's possible to download the starter app's from github, but I tried to transform the courses from html to pdf and the google-codelabs's tag surpassed me ... please I dont think that I'm the only one in the world wanting to learn and without money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ScnPdVWxnPxgeFUrXwxFEjXCURpUqsHN) that contains some PDFs and presentations of the course.

In the link you sent, that link is called "Slide decks".

Comment: Thank you! the real problem was the "codelabs" and luckily those are like pdf's in that folder

Answer (score 0):

Use Evernote web clipper ( an extension of chrome by evernote )

Save the page as an article in your evernote using this. You can do this for all pages in 15-20 min. No need for a pdf. Actually it is better to have an editable note in evernote, so that you can highlight, write short notes etc.

[image: Getting whole page as an editable note]

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the website using Internet Download Manager's Grabber Option.
I then put the downloaded project into Wamp's www project and opened the project in my browser. Worked just fine for me.